# uitableview reset delete button

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, button

In my uitableview, when the user sets the mode to edit and tries to delete a row, I do some validations to check if that row is ok to be deleted. If not, I would like to reset the row to the previous state, i.e without the delete button on the right, but just the minus horizontal button on the left.

Which method would I use to do the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if(fails)
{
  [self.tableView reloadData];
  [super setEditing:YES animated:YES]; 
  [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will reset just the cell you need to reset.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if(fails)
    {
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

KingofBliss's answer will get the job done, however this is a bit more specific.  This approach will animate the resetting of the delete confirmation and essentially "taps" the delete edit control (an action that resets the confirmation).

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.detailsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *subview, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){

      if([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UITableViewCellEditControl")])
      {
                UIControl *editControl = (UIControl *)subview;
                [editControl sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
      }
```

}];